# Validate Kusto query before submitting it

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way (in Powershell would be best, but also otherwise) to check for KQL syntax before submitting it to a cluster?

I want to check sanity of a KQL code repo in my CI pipeline.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Install :

```bash
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Scope CurrentUser
Register-PackageSource -Name nuget.org -ProviderName NuGet  -Location https://www.nuget.org/api/v2
Install-Package -Name Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Language -ProviderName NuGet -scope CurrentUser
```

Step 2 : Run query :

```bash
$kql="T | project a = a + b | where a > 10.0"

$nuGetPath=Get-Package -Name "Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Language" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Source
$dllPath=(Split-Path -Path $nuGetPath) + "\lib\netstandard2.0\Kusto.Language.dll"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($dllPath)

$kustoParse=[Kusto.Language.KustoCode]::Parse($kql)
$kustoParse.getDiagnostics()
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the [Kusto Query Language parser (.Net library)](https://github.com/microsoft/Kusto-Query-Language) for this, start from the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Kusto-Query-Language/blob/master/src/Kusto.Language/readme.md) doc.

Comment: Hi @Avnera, thanks for reply. I'm really struggling at integrating properly .NET libs into a nice powershell script. Aim is to run the script against Kusto string, e.g. Test-Kusto "T | project a = a + b | where a > 10.0". How to do so? Updated post for first tries.

Comment: I think that you should consider creating a C# assembly with a method that accepts the query string and the schema and outputs to the console the results. Then all you need is to call it from Powershell passing the applicable arguments. This will allow you to avoid compiling the C# code in the Powershell script.